# SSIS to Generate CSV containing ',' but cannot use text qualifier

Tags: sql-server, excel, ssis

I have data that contains a field in which values are separated by ','. Normal procedure may be to use a text qualifier such as " to allow the data to display correctly when dumped to a csv format. However the code that reads in this csv file can't use such a file unless I first open the file and resave. This causes the binary data to change.

Example:

Pre-saving the file manually.

```
"value1","value2","value3_A,value3_B"etc...
```

After opening/resaving the file:

```
value1, value2, value3, "value4_A,value4_B"etc.....
```

How can I progromatically obtain the second result. I'm not sure what excel is acutally doing but my guess is it's using a text qualifier on a specific cell.

The issue is if I do it using method #1 the file is un readable per a script a developer wrote. (at the moment we can't fix that), so I need a work-around.

Any suggestions, thanks.

**UPDATES**
Binary of the file:

Pre-ReSaving (SSIS Original Output to .CSV using txt qualifier (")):

```
"id","type","creation class","index","label","manufacturer","model number","part number","attributes","orientation","internal routes","x","y","width","height","connector"
"10971545","0ccbb2a8-2bea-4038-ab83-c9cced273b61","-225094789","0","Torrance ZENITH - ZTG TRANSFER SWITCH - Panel","Unknown","Torrance ZENITH - ZTG TRANSFER SWITCH - Panel","","M&E=Yes~Input Beaker Rating (A)=100~Input Frequency (Hz)=60~Input Phase=Three~Input Rating (A)=~Input Rating (kVA)=36.0267~Input Voltage (VAC)=208~Output Voltage (VAC)=208~Power Factor=0.8~Rating (A)=100~Rating (kVA)=36~Rating (W)=16640~Rating Per Phase(A)=~Voltage (VDC)=~Weight (kg)=~Image Files=~","0","","0","0","49","49",""
"","4000","-225094829","1003","PowerOut 01","","","","Phase=1P~Voltage (VAC)=208~Rating (A)=100~Voltage (VDC)=~","1",",1001,1002,","-1","3","50","46","PowerCable 20mm (AC)"
"","4000","-225094830","1001","PowerIn 01","","","","Phase=1P~Voltage (VAC)=208~Rating (A)=40~Voltage (VDC)=~","1","","0","-43","50","46","PowerCable 20mm (AC)"
"","4000","-225094830","1002","PowerIn 02","","","","Phase=1P~Voltage (VAC)=208~Rating (A)=40~Voltage (VDC)=~","1","","0","3","50","46","PowerCable 20mm (AC)"
```

Post ReSave (Opening CSV in EXcel (Ctrl+S) Close file>Check binary:

```
id,type,creation class,index,label,manufacturer,model number,part number,attributes,orientation,internal routes,x,y,width,height,connector
10971545,0ccbb2a8-2bea-4038-ab83-c9cced273b61,-225094789,0,Torrance ZENITH - ZTG TRANSFER SWITCH - Panel,Unknown,Torrance ZENITH - ZTG TRANSFER SWITCH - Panel,,M&E=Yes~Input Beaker Rating (A)=100~Input Frequency (Hz)=60~Input Phase=Three~Input Rating (A)=~Input Rating (kVA)=36.0267~Input Voltage (VAC)=208~Output Voltage (VAC)=208~Power Factor=0.8~Rating (A)=100~Rating (kVA)=36~Rating (W)=16640~Rating Per Phase(A)=~Voltage (VDC)=~Weight (kg)=~Image Files=~,0,,0,0,49,49,
,4000,-225094829,1003,PowerOut 01,,,,Phase=1P~Voltage (VAC)=208~Rating (A)=100~Voltage (VDC)=~,1,",1001,1002,",-1,3,50,46,PowerCable 20mm (AC)
,4000,-225094830,1001,PowerIn 01,,,,Phase=1P~Voltage (VAC)=208~Rating (A)=40~Voltage (VDC)=~,1,,0,-43,50,46,PowerCable 20mm (AC)
,4000,-225094830,1002,PowerIn 02,,,,Phase=1P~Voltage (VAC)=208~Rating (A)=40~Voltage (VDC)=~,1,,0,3,50,46,PowerCable 20mm (AC)
```

You can see in result 2, that the column internal routes has a field which is text qualified while the rest of the file isn't ",1001,1002,"
In result 1 the entire output is text qualified and will not work.

Trying to understand why, and how to achieve the same result progromatically.

**Current Solution (Hacky)**:
The output files are created using a view from stage tables where I process and format the data for my purposes. I've just appended " to the front and end of the field. Which gives me the desired output. Just feels hacky and who knows how the data may be passed over in the future. Still looking to understand dynamic solutions without too much vb or C# as this adds complexity I'd like to avoid.

.

Comment: Use SQL Porosity: https://theithobbit.blogspot.com/2016/09/sql-porosity-csv-element-calculation.html

Comment: Can you show what SSIS actually exports, i.e. the raw CSV file?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Added CSV output from SSIS. See updates. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You could use a Script task to write the output.  That would allow you to control the formatting yourself, using either VB or C# syntax.  More details here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/extending-packages-scripting-data-flow-script-component-types/creating-a-destination-with-the-script-component

Answer (score 0):

Current Solution (Hacky): The output files are created using a view from stage tables where I process and format the data for my purposes. I've just appended " to the front and end of the field. Which gives me the desired output. Just feels hacky and who knows how the data may be passed over in the future. Still looking to understand dynamic solutions without too much vb or C# as this adds complexity I'd like to avoid.